# How to resolve class Not found exception in STS

Tags: spring-boot, jar, classnotfoundexception, spring-tool-suite

I installed STS(spring tool suit) and just created a maven spring starter project to print hello world.
I got the error:class not found exception. Then I gone through some of previous solutions on this website where they told it was because of missing jar files. So add jar file related to that class.

I do not even know what is jar file, where it will be in the system and how to find that jar file, which is causing that particular class which is not found.

In sts.
I am expecting that I get the detailed solution,  if possible with screenshots.so that I can successfully run projects in sts.

Comment: please provide detailed steps what exactly you did to run into this problem, also pasting in the exact error message could be helpful here

Comment: Please share error message you are getting.